# Avoiding multiple calls to the same function in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that returns a tuple like the following:

```
def foo(i,j):
    # does stuff
    return (m,n)
```

I want to do a double list comprehension over both inputs and get the value of the sum of both elements in the returned tuple. The easiest way I could think to do this is:

`[foo(i,j)[0] + foo(i,j)[1] for i in x for j in y]`

The problem with this approach is that `foo` gets called twice per pair of `i,j`, making the list comprehension slower than necessary. How can I change the list comprehension so that `foo` only gets called once per pair of `i,j`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Walrus operator](https://medium.com/better-programming/three-ways-to-use-the-walrus-operator-in-python-d5550f3a7dd) with Python 3.8+

```
[p[0] + p[1] for i in x for j in y if (p := foo(i,j))]
```

Need the if condition to make it a valid usage with double for loop (not needed with a single for-loop).  But, if always True since foo returns a tuple.

**Better Version** (courtesy @ MisterMiyagi)

```
[(p:=foo(i, j))[0] + p[1] for i in x for j in y]
```

This gets by the need for the if conditional.

Comment: Nice :-) Wasn't familiar with this one

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's the most general

Comment: @bleutooth65--yes, Walrus is a great feature with 3.8+.

Comment: There is no need for the hazardous ``if`` clause! Use ``[(p:=foo(i, j)[0] + p[1] for i in x for j in y]`` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi--is there an error in your expression?  I get a syntax error using as is: `p := foo(i,j)]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @DarrylG There is one parenthesis missing. It should be ``[(p:=foo(i, j))[0] + p[1] for i in x for j in y]``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi--I had guessed that looking at the expression, but it gives me the same error after correcting.

Comment: @DarrylG What error does it give? What code do you run? The snippet from your earlier comment, ``p := foo(i,j)] ``, does not match either of my code versions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi--ah wait--I took out some code and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[sum(foo(i,j)) for i in x for j in y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Python's built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
[sum(foo(i,j)) for i in x for j in y]
```

sample run:

```
def foo(m,n):
    print(f'called: foo({m},{n})')
    return m,n

x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

print('Run without sum() - expect 8 calls')
[foo(i,j)[0] + foo(i,j)[1] for i in x for j in y]

print('\nRun with sum() - expect 4 calls')
[sum(foo(i,j)) for i in x for j in y]

> Run without sum() - expect 8 calls
> called: foo(1,3)
> called: foo(1,3) 
> called: foo(1,4) 
> called: foo(1,4)
> called: foo(2,3) 
> called: foo(2,3) 
> called: foo(2,4) 
> called: foo(2,4)
> [4, 5, 5, 6]
>
> Run with sum() - expect 4 calls
> called: foo(1,3)
> called: foo(1,4)
> called: foo(2,3)
> called: foo(2,4)
> [4, 5, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `operator` module provides all operators as first-class functions. `operator.add(a, b)` is equivalent to `a + b`, and `operator.add(*ab)` is equivalent to `operator.add(ab[0], ab[1])`.

```
from operator import add
[add(*foo(i,j)) for i in x for j in y]
```

Using `add` is slightly faster than `sum`:

```
In [1]: %timeit [add(*foo(i, j)) for i in range(50) for j in range(50)]
409 µs ± 8.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [2]: %timeit [sum(foo(i, j)) for i in range(50) for j in range(50)]
554 µs ± 5.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [3]: %timeit [add(*foo(i, j)) for i in range(500) for j in range(500)]
47.2 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [4]: %timeit [sum(foo(i, j)) for i in range(500) for j in range(500)]
61.5 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```